# std::list iterator, no operator "=" matches these operands

Tags: c++, list

It's my first time using lists so sorry if i'm doing something stupid

```
std::list<AbstractBlock>::iterator i;

    for (i = universe.getLoadedBlocks(); i != universe.getLoadedBlocks().end; i++){

    }
```

universe.getLoadedBlocks() returns and `std::list<AbstractBlock>` list, however I keep getting the error:

```
1   IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
        operand types are: std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<AbstractBlock>>> = std::list<AbstractBlock, std::allocator<AbstractBlock>>
```

Comment: Small tip: it's good to know how to use iterators eventually, but if you're just doing a simple iteration over the blocks, and have a C++11 compiler, you can use `for (auto& block : universe.getLoadedBlocks()) { ...use block here... }`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first condition of the `for()` loop, you are trying to assign a `std::list` to a `std::list::iterator`, which is what the compiler is complaining about. Your code needs to be more like this instead:

```
std::list<AbstractBlock>::iterator i;

std::list<AbstractBlock> &blocks = universe.getLoadedBlocks();
for (i = blocks.begin(); i != blocks.end(); i++){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does `getLoadedBlocks()` return? I suspect it returns a *reference* to a `std::list<AbstractBlock>` container. In that case the proper `for` syntax is

```
for (std::list<AbstractBlock>::iterator i = universe.getLoadedBlocks().begin(); 
     i != universe.getLoadedBlocks().end(); 
     ++i)
{

}
```

(and prefer to use prefix `++` in C++).

But if it returns `std::list<AbstractBlock>` by value, then you will have to reconsider the whole approach. In such case you cannot call `getLoadedBlocks()` repeatedly and expect the iterators to be comparable.

Comment: The question says what `getLoadedBlocks()` returns: "*universe.getLoadedBlocks() returns and std::list<AbstractBlock> list*".

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: If it returns a list, instead of a *reference* to a list, then the OP is in trouble.

Comment: If you compile with optimization, chances are that it doesn't make a difference whether you preincrement or postincrement STL iterators.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Another question asked by the same poster on SO actually shows that `getLoadedBlocks()` actually returns a *pointer* to `std::list<AbstractBlock>`. Go figure...